# Python - Convert unicode entity into unicode symbol

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, unicode-string

My request.json(), When I loop through the dict it returns from an API, returns "v\u00F6lk" (without the quotes)

But I want "völk" (without the quotes), which is how it is raw in the API.

How do I convert?

```
request = requests.post(get_sites_url, headers=api_header, params=search_sites_params, timeout=http_timeout_seconds)
return_search_results = request.json()
for site_object in return_search_results['data']:
    site_name = str(site_object['name'])
    site_name_fixed=str(site_name.encode("utf-8").decode())
    print("fixed site_name: " + site_name_fixed)
```

Comment: Does it return literally `"v\u00F6lk"`, including quotes? Was the original JSON `"\"v\\u00F6lk\""`? If so you're looking at double encoded JSON, which you need to JSON-decode twice, i.e. `json.loads(request.json())`. Otherwise, please be more detailed.

Comment: Without the quotes. Edited original to show that. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a difference? My understanding is that they would be essentially the same thing but the display of the accented characters would depend on your font. for example `print("v\u00F6lk")` gives me `völk`. Also `"v\u00F6lk" == 'völk'` is True for me.

Comment: Can you please show a [mre] of the JSON and how you access it? JSON may represent unicode via escapes, but the runtime representation of the data are the corresponding character symbols – unless of course one displays them in a way that forces escapes again.

Comment: Thanks. Not "reproducible" because I'd have to share the API url and key. I'll modify my question to show code without that so maybe you will see what I'm missing.

Comment: What would really help here is a sample of `print(repr(return_search_results))`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Guess, the API is actually returning the literal version, so he is really getting:

```
"v\\u00F6lk"
```

Printing that gives what we think we are getting from the api:

```
print("v\\u00F6lk")
v\u00F6lk
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to do this, but encoding it with "utf-8", then using "unicode_escape" to decode seemed to work:

```
>>> print(bytes("v\\u00F6lk", "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
völk
>>> print("v\\u00F6lk".encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape"))
völk
```

Comment: Fails for *"combined"* encoding scheme e.g. (an artificial case) `"v\\u00F6lkö".encode( "utf-8").decode( "unicode_escape")` returns `'völkÃ¶'`. The following method does not fail: `"v\\u00F6lkö".encode( 'raw_unicode_escape').decode( 'unicode_escape')` returns `'völkö'`.